# Readline() in R reads the next line

Tags: r

I want some user input and I want to use readline for that. However, when I execute the code below it uses "test <- "sometext" directly as input and does not wait for the user to respond.

How can I let the code stop running whenever I call readline, so that R waits for the user to respond?

```
fun <- function() {
   ANSWER <- readline("Are you a satisfied R user? ")
   if (substr(ANSWER, 1, 1) == "n")
     cat("This is impossible.  YOU LIED!\n")
   else
     cat("I knew it.\n")
}
fun()
test <- "sometext"
someCode <- "someCode"
```

This gives the following output:

```
> fun <- function() {
+   ANSWER <- readline("Are you a satisfied R user? ")
+   if (substr(ANSWER, 1, 1) == "n")
+     cat("This is impossible.  YOU LIED!\n")
+   else
+     cat("I knew it.\n")
+ }
> fun()
Are you a satisfied R user? test <- "sometext"
I knew it.
> someCode <- "someCode"
```

Answer (score 0):

`R` is waiting for input and perceives the code after the `fun()` call (that is copied pasted eg `test <- "sometext"`) is the input. If you don't want this to happen, you can wrap the calls into their own function and call that function:

```
foo = function(){
    fun()
    test <- "sometext"
    someCode <- "someCode"
}
foo()
```

Comment: is that the only option?

Comment: That, or copy/paste line by line.